# FIrebase firestore onSnapshot not firing on change

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following a simple tutorial on Firebase 9. Everything worked fine until I tried to use onSnapshot method to get the snapshot of changes in db every time the cahnge occurs.
But onSnapshot is not working. I mean it work only for the initial fetch of data, but does not execute the callback function when the change occurs.
I am following a tutorial so my code is identical to the code from the tutorial. My question is whether there is something I need to do in the console to rectify this, some kind of rules or permissions or something.

**My code:**

```
const colRef = collection(db, 'books');

const q = query(colRef, where('author', '==', 'patrick rothfuss'));

onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  let books = []
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    books.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
  })
  console.log(books)
})
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Can you add an `error` callback? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot_4. "does not execute the callback function when the change occurs" => How is the change occurring? How do you create this change (through your app, through the console, ...)?

Comment: I tried introducing onError optional callback, but it still doesn't work. I am not getting to that part. It doesn't seem to be registering the change at all. I get no error, with onError or without it.

Comment: Hmmm.... Your code seems correct. Difficult to say more without any error...

Comment: That is why I think that there could be something wrong with my rules, permissions or something, and I say this fully aware that I could be saying nonsense. :).

Comment: But you said that the first listener triggering is ok ("it works only for the initial fetch of data") so it means that it shouldn't not be a problem of this kind (rules, permissions)...

Comment: If you find @RenaudTarnec's comment helpful, kindly post it as an answer. In this way, you'll be able to help the community.

Comment: I also facing this problem, any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem too. It works for fetching but using updateDoc method seems not working unless I refresh the page, the updated content shows up.

Comment: I found onSnapshot doesn't work locally when running Firestore in the emulator. When I deployed it, it works as expected. I don't get any errors, just no callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that I imported `collection` from the lite version:

`import { collection } from "firebase/firestore/lite";`

After I changed it

`import { collection } from "firebase/firestore";`

All is working well. Also, make sure other functions are imported from a normal version.

You can read more about the lite version here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/firestore-lite

You can see it doesn't support snapshot listeners.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use snapshot.docChanges().forEach method to read and detect changes in data on real time.

I recommend you use this method to modify the array when a change occur.

You can view the code here: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/1c4c6834f310bf53a98b3fa3c2e2191396cacd69/snippets/firestore-next/test-firestore/listen_diffs.js#L8-L23

Comment: The content of my callback function inside onSnapshot is not my problem. My problem seems to be that that callback is not being executed after a change. It executes only on initial fetch, when the page reloads.

Comment: yeah, with snapshot.docChanges().forEach you will get changes everytime it occur

Comment: const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
    // your code
  });
});

Comment: Nope, tried that.